# Prove $1<ab+bc+ca-abc<\frac{28}{27}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a$, $b$, $c$ are three positive real numbers such that:

$a+b>c$
$b+c>a$
$c+a>b$
$a+b+c=2$

$a$, $b$ and $c$ might be or might not be equal in value

Show that:
$$1<ab+bc+ca-abc<\frac{28}{27}$$

From the first half of the question, I realised that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the sides of a triangle whose perimeter is $2$. However, I'm unable to solve this problem, even after using some standard inequalities.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: You should include your attempts, you may have been on the right track!

Comment: If you are unable to solve the problem even after using some inequalities, please post that solution, regardless if it failed. Users may provide insights about your solution and help you better.

Comment: Hint: Notice that the problem is symmetric with respect to permuting the names of $a,b,c$. In that case, it may be useful to consider a polynomial whose roots are $a,b,c$, i.e. $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$. Expand it, then collect like terms at powers of $x$. Then see what happens if you let $x=1$ and notice that $1=(a+b+c)/2=p$, the semiperimeter of the triangle. Remember the formula that has $\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$? That should be useful for $>1$. Now use AM-GM inequality for $\sqrt[3]{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$, that should help with $\le 28/27$.

Comment: $a=b=c=2/3$ gives exactly $28/27$, so your condition should be $\leq 28/27$.

Comment: $c=2-a-b \Rightarrow a<1 \land b<1 \land a+b>1 \Rightarrow 0<a<1, 1-a<b<1$. Then put $c$ in $d=ab+bc+ca-abc$ to get $-(1-a)b^2+(1-a)(2-a)b+(2-a)a$. This expression has minimum 1 at $b\to 1-a$ and $b\to 1$ (value 1 is impossible so $d>1$). Maximum at $b=(2-a)/2$ is $d_{max}=1-a^3/4+a^2/4$. The maximum value of $d_{max}$ is at $a=2/3$ and is equal to $28/27$. So $1 < d \leq 28/27$.

Answer (score 3):

I'll write up my comment as an answer. Consider the polynomial
$$
\begin{split}
f(x)&=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\\
&=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc\\
&=x^3-2x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc.
\end{split}
$$
Then $f(1)=1-2+ab+bc+ca-abc=ab+bc+ca-abc-1$, so we need to show that
$0<f(1)\le 1/27$.

Note that $1=(a+b+c)/2=p$, the semiperimeter of the triangle with sides $a,b,c$. This triangle is not degenerate since all the inequalities in the problem statement are strict. Therefore, its area is positive. But the area of this triangle is
$$
A=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}=\sqrt{1\cdot f(1)}=\sqrt{f(1)},
$$
so $f(1)=A^2>0$. On the other hand, by the AM-GM inequality,
$$
\begin{split}
\sqrt[3]{f(1)}&=\sqrt[3]{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}\\
&\le \frac{(p-a)+(p-b)+(p-c)}{3}\\
&=\frac{3p-(a+b+c)}{3}=\frac{3-2}{3}=\frac{1}{3},
\end{split}
$$
i.e. $f(1)\le (1/3)^3=1/27$.

In fact, we can use AM-GM inequality on any triangle to show that its area $A\le\dfrac{p^2}{3\sqrt{3}}$, where $p$ is its semiperimeter.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how "problem is symmetric hence consider $\prod (x-a)$?"    $\quad$ I get that the main contribution here is recognizing $ (1-a)(1-b)(1-c) = ab+bc+ca-abc - 1$, but that could have been evaluated directly.  $\quad$ Put another way, if we wanted to find the range of $ab+bc+ca + a^2b^2c^2$, then does your hint work?

Comment: @CalvinLin In this particular problem, we have a difference of elementary symmetric polynomials of degree 2 and 3, that’s what suggests considering that polynomial in $x$. In other problems, it may need to be a different symmetric function of $a,b,c$. There is no need to always consider this particular polynomial, I just wanted to give a hint at kind of methods could be used in a more general situation.

Answer (score 3):

**Proof**:

Let
$$x = \frac{a + b - c}{2} > 0, \quad y = \frac{b + c - a}{2} > 0, \quad z = \frac{c + a - b}{2} > 0.$$
Correspondingly, $a = z + x, b = x + y, c = y + z$ (the so-called Ravi's substitution).
We have $a + b + c = 2(x + y + z)$. Thus, $x + y + z = 1$.

Also, we have
\begin{align*}
 &ab + bc + ca - abc \\
 =\,& (z + x)(x + y) + (x + y)(y + z) + (y + z)(z + x) - (z + x)(x + y)(y + z)\\
 =\,& (z + x + y + z)(x + y) + (y + z)(z + x)(1 - x - y)\\
 =\,& (1 + z)(1 - z) + [xy + z(x + y + z)]z \\
 =\,& 1 - z^2 + (xy + z)z \\
 =\,& 1 + xyz.
\end{align*}

First, $ab + bc + ca - abc = 1 + xyz > 1$.

Second, using AM-GM, we have $xyz \le (\frac{x + y + z}{3})^3 = \frac{1}{27}$ with equality if and only if $x = y = z = 1/3$.
Thus, we have $ab + bc + ca - abc \le \frac{28}{27}$ with equality if and only if $a = b = c = 2/3$.

We are done.

---

*Remark*: Actually, we can prove the following identity:
\begin{align*}
 &ab + bc + ca - abc\\
 \equiv\,& 1 + \frac{(a + b - c)(b + c - a)(c + a - b)}{8}\\
 & + \frac{1}{8}(a + b + c - 2)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2ab - 2bc - 2ca + 2a + 2b + 2c + 4).
\end{align*}

Comment: I have the same idea ! (+1) :-)

Comment: @ErikSatie Nice. Thank you.